# Can I get Contact Number while login in app using Facebook along with other fields like fbUserName, fbEmail,fbPicture etc.?

Tags: java, android

I want to fetch the Contact Number using facebook login in my app, is there any way to fetch the contact number ??

I have to show the facebook user details in my app and if the user hasn't added his contact Number then I simply set the ContactNo column as empty where I want to show the basic user details.

I have fetched the user details like this:

```
 //useLoginInformation() method is called from the CallbackManager listener to display details once the user has successfully logged in

private void useLoginInformation(AccessToken accessToken) {
        /**
         Creating the GraphRequest to fetch user details
         1st Param - AccessToken
         2nd Param - Callback (which will be invoked once the request is successful)
         **/
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            //OnCompleted is invoked once the GraphRequest is successful
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                try {
                    String name = object.getString("name");
                    String email = object.getString("email");
                    String id=object.getString("id");
                    String image_url="https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=normal";

//Send facebook user details from login activity to FacebookUserDetails activity

Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,FacebookUserDetails.class);
                    intent.putExtra("facebookUsername",name);
                    intent.putExtra("facebookUserEmail",email);
                    intent.putExtra("facebookPic",image_url);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    finish();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        // We set parameters to the GraphRequest using a Bundle.
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "name,email,id,picture");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        // Initiate the GraphRequest
        request.executeAsync();
    }
```